# JMS bridge in JBoss EAP 7.1 not pushing messages to destination

Tags: jms, jboss-eap-7

I have JMS bridge from JBoss EAP 7.1 to Weblogic 12. When I add message to source queue locally (i.e. from application which is deployed on above JBoss EAP 7.1) JMS messages gets delivered to destination. But sometimes due to some reason we have to re-send JMS messages again which lost midway and not reached to target queue on Weblogic 12. In that case we have different application  running on different JBoss EAP 7.1 instance from where we remotely add message to JMS queue on JBoss EAP 7.1 having JMS bridge configured. But JMS bridge is not pushing JMS message to target though messages are getting added to source queue. Can anyone help as to why this is occurring?

Comment: Can you confirm the bridge is connected to the destination and there isn't some kind of connectivity problem preventing the bridge from moving messages to the destination?

Comment: I get to see this message in server startup logs "jms bridge started". Also when sending messages locally bridge is pushing messages to destination, but not when we trying to send remotely.